# Can not import cython .pyx after installation cython

Tags: python, animation-nodes

I am using Blender 2.83 in Windows. I installed cython on 2.83\python\bin. And also installed Vc.redist.x64. When I import a pyx file in Animation Nodes by below:

```
import nodes.mesh.c_utils
```

It shows the 'import error:building module nodes.mesh.c_utils failed':

> [distutils.errors.CompileError:command c:\...\\cl.exe failed with exit status 2 \n]